# Fork A Repo via GitHub API by curl

Tags: command-line, git, curl, api, forking

How to fork a Repo via GitHub API?

I'm looking at GitHub Fork API doc at
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#create-a-fork
and I'm quite confused as how to do it.

> **Create a fork**
>   Create a fork for the authenticated user.
>
> POST /repos/:owner/:repo/forks

So if I want to clone **github.com/neurobin/shc** as mine, *github.com/myghid/shc*, what exact curl command I should be using? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fork a repo you must query the github API endpoint. Here's an example, assuming that you have created your github API token already:

```
curl -X POST -u "<github_username>:<github_token>" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/neurobin/shc/forks"
```

When you will ever see extra parameters in github API, you can pass them inside the JSON object. In case of `organization` parameter for the fork API, full query would look like this:

```
curl -X POST -u "<github_username>:<github_token>" \
    -d "{\"organization\": \"your_org_here\"}" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/neurobin/shc/forks"
```

After that you can clone it with simple:

```
git clone https://github.com/your_github_nick/shc
```

Comment: Thanks! would there be any differences if the repo is owned/under an organization instead of an end user? e.g., what if I want to clone a repo into a github organization? How to specify the `organization` string, the optional parameter to specify the organization name if forking into an organization? Thanks

Comment: @xpt i updated the answer